# NAT: change dst ip or port based on src ip

Tags: nat

Is there such option to change the destination ip / port if traffic arrives from specific source ip?

Comment: Yes. Just specify the source IP in the same NAT rule.

Comment: @LSerni, can you please show me the example of the command and how to verify it? I've tried some command for iptables yesterday, but when checking `iptables -L` I could not see it and checking the functionality - it didn't worked

Comment: Add the iptables command you tried to the question. You should have something like ` iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.1.15 -d 192.168.1.42 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.5.137`, with a **higher** priority (lower rule number) than the default NAT for the 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Comment: This is more or the less what I've did.
Is there someway to verify that it is existing in the iptables? Executing `iptables -L` I couldn't see it